# how can i select only last span element in a div ? it should not select if only one span in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have HTML like this

```js
$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText:last:not(".labelText:first")').css('margin-left','150px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementContainers">
<span class="labelText mandatory" >First Name</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="text" class="customInput" id="firstName"  name="firstName" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required/>

<span class="labelText" >Last Name</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="text" class="customInput" id="lastName" value=""  name="lastName"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}" required/>
</div>
<div class="elementContainers">
<span class="labelText mandatory"  >Gender</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="radio" name="gender"  >Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" >Female
</div>
```

I want to select last `labelText` in every `elementContainer`

```
$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText:last')
```

This gives me exactly what i need,but i need to check that first and last should not be the same(`elementContainer` should contain two elements  )

How can i check that with `:not` selector or any other selector.

I have tried something like this

```
$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText:last:not(".labelText:first")')
```

But its not working,its returning no elements.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check that the length of `$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText')` is greater than 1

Comment: What's with using `Array.length`?
If lte 1 you don't select it.

Comment: try this $('.elementContainers .labelText:last').not($('.elementContainers .labelText:first'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the last span in a div, but only where there is more than one span in the div, then the following selector should work.

```
$('div').find('span:gt(0):last').addClass('selected');
```

It's finding any span's at an index > 0 (https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/), and then getting the last of those.

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/vnorunwm/

Your code could look something like this....

```
$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText:gt(0):last').css('margin-left','150px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/qoebk8j9/

Comment: Thanks :). JSPerf vs Kishor's (corrected) solution: http://jsperf.com/last-not-first-vs-gt-0-last. This is _slightly_ more performant ;).

Answer (score 2):

If there is as option to change html I will make a try using `label` instead of `span` and without using `jquery` at all only with css:

```css
.elementContainers label:last-of-type:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementContainers">
  <label class="labelText mandatory">First Name</label>
  <span class="spacing"></span>
  <input type="text" class="customInput" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required/>

  <label class="labelText">Last Name</label>
  <span class="spacing"></span>
  <input type="text" class="customInput" id="lastName" value="" name="lastName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}" required/>
</div>
<div class="elementContainers">
  <label class="labelText mandatory">Gender</label>
  <span class="spacing"></span>
  <input type="radio" name="gender">Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender">Female
</div>
```

**References**

[:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Alast-of-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` method and you can return that element which have `.labelText` length of 2:

```js
$('.elementContainers').filter(function(){
 return $(this).find('.labelText').length == 2
}).find('.labelText').last().css('margin-left','150px');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementContainers">
<span class="labelText mandatory" >First Name</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="text" class="customInput" id="firstName"  name="firstName" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required/>

<span class="labelText" >Last Name</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="text" class="customInput" id="lastName" value=""  name="lastName"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}" required/>
</div>
<div class="elementContainers">
<span class="labelText mandatory"  >Gender</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="radio" name="gender"  >Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" >Female
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that the length of your collection is greater than 1 before proceeding...

```
if ($('.elementContainers').find('.labelText').length > 1) {
    $('.elementContainers').find('.labelText:last').css('margin-left','150px');
}
```

Comment: `$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText').length` is calculating over all elementContainers,so its passing all.In the code i posted length will be 3 so all three are passing.
The answer what you gave is correct but i need to use `.each` function on every `$('.elementContainers').find('.labelText')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.elementContainers .labelText:last').not($('.elementContainers .labelText:first'))
```

Comment: This selector isn't _quite_ right for some edge-cases. See http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/vnorunwm/2/ . Would need to be http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/vnorunwm/1/ .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('.elementContainers').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('.labelText').length > 1 ){
    $(this).find('.labelText:last').css('margin-left','150px');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementContainers">
<span class="labelText mandatory" >First Name</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="text" class="customInput" id="firstName"  name="firstName" value="" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required/>

<span class="labelText" >Last Name</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="text" class="customInput" id="lastName" value=""  name="lastName"  pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,}" required/>
</div>
<div class="elementContainers">
<span class="labelText mandatory"  >Gender</span>
<span class="spacing"></span>
<input type="radio" name="gender"  >Male 
<input type="radio" name="gender" >Female
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to first check the length of span element inside div if length is greater then 1 then get the last span inside div ,

you can get the length using

```
var span_lenght = $( ".elementContainers span" ).length;
if(span_lenght>1)
{
  // write your code here
}
```